# Adding instruction to jupiter swapTransaction

Tags: web3.js, versionedtransactions, jupiter

I using Jupiter v4 for swapping. To SwapInstruction from Jupiter, I add some of my instruction and try to execute the transaction, but receive sometimes error:

> encoded solana_sdk::transaction::versioned::VersionedTransaction too
> large: 1704 byte.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm running into this same issue, but with Jupiter V6 API. I am already using address lookup tables. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your transaction is exceeding the maximum allowed size of 1232 bytes.

It looks like you're already using Versioned Transactions, you could try adding the addresses in the swap to an Address Lookup Table and use it with your Versioned Transaction if you aren't already doing that.

https://solanacookbook.com/guides/versioned-transactions.html#facts
https://solanacookbook.com/guides/versioned-transactions.html#address-lookup-tables-lut

https://github.com/solana-developers/web3-examples/blob/main/address-lookup-tables/tests/test.ts